# TinyMCE, allow data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, tinymce, rte

I have to use the HTML 5 [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) in Tiny MCE, but the editor always clear them, as it's not an attribute known by the default [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) configuration.

So I have 2 problems here:

- the data attribute is dynamic ( it could be data-options, data-test, data-foo, etc... ) So I would need a wildcard value or something.
- I want to allow the data attribute for all tags.

So far, I've tried:

```
extended_valid_elements : '@[id|class|title|style|data-options]',
```

And:

```
extended_valid_elements : '*[id|class|title|style|data*]',
```

But it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 7):

`extended_valid_elements` is not the best choice here.
Hava a look at the `valid_elements` [setting](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements). Here is an example

```
    // The valid_elements option defines which elements will remain in the edited text when the editor saves.
    valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style|data-options|data*]," +
    "a[name|href|target|title]," +
    "#p,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-b,-i,-u," +
    "-span[data-mce-type],hr",
```

Comment: Why extended_valid_elements is not the best choice ? Also, from what I've understood, the valid_elements option must define all the tags&attribute, as it will override the default one (it will not add/append/merge my definition to the actual one). I don't want my TinyMCE initialization to be 300+lines longs at every place I need the editor...

Comment: In this case you are not adding new elements to the editor. You want to add an attribute only. It might not be very concenient, but does it work using the valid_elements parameter?

Comment: @Thariama , 
I am having the same issue as FMaz008, but with tinymce stripping out my input 'style' attribute.  I have `valid_elements : "@[id|class|style|title|dir<ltr?rtl|lang|xml::lang],"`, etc..  but it seems to ignore that 'style' is listed there.  If I add `[style]` to the specific tag I am using for my test (in the `valid_elements` def.) , it still does not work.

Comment: yes, Thariama is correct. 
See here if you are using CodeIgniter and also thinking that tinymce is stripping out more than your tinymce config. says it should be stripping:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290121/how-to-prevent-tinymce-from-stripping-the-style-attribute-from-input-element/10308817#10308817

Answer (score 4):

I am using:

```
extended_valid_elements: "+@[data-options]"
```

and it works for me. (TinyMCE 4.3.11. Notice the + sign?)

Comment: This works for me but custom attribute is not supported

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working for me. Can you give a bit more details?

Comment: Thank you, saved my day. Custom attributes are indeed not supported, because AFAIK they are not valid HTML, but you can use HTML5 custom data attributes ("data-*", as in "data-myamazingcustomattribute")

Answer (score 2):

I setup for certain element and add all necessary attributes like this

```
extended_valid_elements: "a[id|class|title|style|data-*|hx-*]"
```