# Embed pinterest board widget in Plone 4.1.x

Tags: tinymce, plone

In Plone 4.3 i can embed a Pinterest board widget by adding this snippet to the html of a Plone page:

```
<a data-pin-do="embedBoard" href="http://www.pinterest.com/pinterest/pin-pets/">
Follow Pinterest's board Pin pets on Pinterest.</a>
<!-- Please call pinit.js only once per page -->
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

In Plone 4.1.x this doesn't work as the `data-pin-do` attribute is stripped from the html. I guess this changed in later versions of TinyMCE (Plone 4.1.6 ships with Products.TinyMCE 1.2.12 which contains TinyMCE 3.2.6)?

Or is this somehow configurable? Is it feasible to use Products.TinyMCE 1.3.x with Plone 4.1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was discussed in:

- https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12844
- https://dev.plone.org/ticket/11300

The origin is a Problem in TinyMCE's config, check [TinyMCE, allow data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744903/tinymce-allow-data-attribute)

You have to extend the `valid_elements` setting of tinymce. 
For this you have to fork Products.TinyMCE or patch it.

It's configured in the utilities.py (Plone 4.3) https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/blob/23145c0a28f9ecde1fd5687ce459beaa4eacc9d8/Products/TinyMCE/utility.py#L414